# Error while updating ece-tools version - Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, magento2-cloud

I am using magento2.2.6 cloud version and while updating ece-tools version and push changes to cloud environment it is displaying below error.

```
W: Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
W: Generating optimized autoload files
W: File doesn't exist: bin/docker
W: Check "chmod" section in composer.json of magento/ece-tools package.
Could not open input file: ./vendor/bin/ece-tools
```

However I tried to remove container-interop/container-interop package but still having same error.

**I have already followed below documents provided by magento.**
https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/ece-tools-upgrade-project.html#remove-deprecated-packages

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/ece-tools-update.html

Anyone have idea about this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing files from **bin** directory.

Running **composer clear-cache && composer update** afterward should add new binary files and solve the problem.